# Is there a way to improve this SQL query with 3 entities?

Tags: sql, join

So in a facebook like wall we have the entities: 
WallPost. (id, user_id, message)
User. (id, name)
Connections. (user1_id, user2_id)

I want with one SQL query to get all the wall posts of a user with id: x (example 5)
I tried:

```
select wallPost.* from 
wallPost, Connections
Where 
wallPost.user_id = x
or 
(Connections.user1_id =x and wallPost.user_id = connections.user2_id) 
or  
(Connections.user2_id =x and wallPost.user_id = connections.user1_id) 
ORDER BY <field_name>
```

So beside the performance problem that this may create, it's also not working correctly when the user doesn't have any connections. I don't want to use two queries because I don't want to sort the results.

Thank you

Comment: If you want to join two tables where one of them may not have records pointed to by the other, you want a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I can't just use a left join here. Because what I am trying to get are all user's posts AND posts of users who have a connection with the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want records from `wallPost`.  I would suggest that you remove `Connections` table in the `from` clause and put the logic in subqueries using `exists`:

```
select wp.*
from wallPost wp 
where wp.user_id = x or 
      exists (select 1 from Connections c where c.user1_id = x and wp.user_id = c.user2_id) or
      exists (select 1 from Connections c where c.user2_id = x and wp.user_id = c.user1_id)
order by <field_name>;
```

For best performance, you would want two indexes, one on `Connections(user2_id, user1_id)` and the other on `Connections(user1_id, user2_id)`.

Comment: Did you leave out the `EXISTS` keywords, or is this a syntax I don't know?

Comment: I tried using the sub queries like you have them here but it didn't work, what does "1" mean in the sub query?  I got it working using IN but again, I don't think it's the best solution: <br/> **select wp.*
from posts wp 
where 
wp.user_id = 1 
or 
(wp.user_id in
      (select c.user2_id from connections c where c.user1_id = 1 and wp.user_id = c.user2_id) 
)
or
(wp.user_id in (
      (select c.user1_id from connections c where c.user2_id = 1 and wp.user_id = c.user1_id)))**

Answer (score 0):

```
select wp.*
from wallPost wp 
where 
wp.user_id = x 
or 
(wp.user_id in
      (select c.user2_id from connections c where c.user1_id = x ) 
)
or
(wp.user_id in (
      (select c.user1_id from connections c where c.user2_id = x )))
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to tune this query. using "IN ( SELECT ... )" is not going to make it faster.

Comment: Yes that's right, I am using solution given by @Gordon Linoff. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you do this?

```
    SELECT WP.* FROM [WallPost] WP WITH (NOLOCK)  
       LEFT JOIN [Connections] CN WITH (NOLOCK) 
          ON ((WP.[User_Id] = CN.[User1_Id]) OR (WP.[User_Id] = CN.[User2_Id))
    WHERE (WP.[User_Id] = X)
```

The LEFT JOIN will take care of users who have no connections.

Comment: Thank you, Mysql doesn't support WITH clause http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23156, this query will return the all wallPosts made by user x, what I am trying to get is all posts made by user x and his connections. So users with no connections should still get results if they have posts something, and users with connections even if they never posted something they should be able to see their connection's posts.

Comment: Ok, then add the where clause: 

        OR (WP.[User_Id] = CN.[User1_Id]) OR (WP.[User_Id] = CN.[User2_Id])